# What's the type (always 0x0) field of a transaction about?

Tags: web3js, transactions

Using web3 you can get all transaction of a block [`web3.eth.getBlock`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html?highlight=getBlock#getblock):

```js
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
const currentBlockNumber = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber()
// true means that transactions should also be included 
const block = await web3.eth.getBlock(currentBlockNumber, true)
```

The block contains some information about the block itself and all `transactions` as an array where one transaction looks like:

```js
{
      "blockHash": "0x576bfc83c1873d6df89abebc75c31710082f0a10bbce79b1d0982e6d580299bc",
      "blockNumber": 8932498,
      "from": "0xc05Ebb6086B917D4D00A425407d8058F98Be8eFb",
      "gas": 211471,
      "gasPrice": "41000000000",
      "hash": "0x2f1367f725e4621ea0f8728f20bdf68ed26e0d72c76393486e6e01e50afba544",
      "input": "0x7ff36ab50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b25bdfcca8130000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000c05ebb6086b917d4d00a425407d8058f98be8efb0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060e4eb740000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000bb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c0000000000000000000000008b9e5495336eb01d4873f21e6784fe83888d7734",
      "nonce": 142,
      "to": "0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E",
      "transactionIndex": 0,
      "value": "1000000000000000000",
      "type": "0x0",
      "v": "0x94",
      "r": "0x4f4b29d5c8fc8537d77f5573eeb1cb2163b4d624984b1fa1a880077445ae3195",
      "s": "0x6b8c494747117350dc37d75e5a17c7d9a06ea0a5eabbb623866c165114744a67"
}
```

**Question**

What is the `type` field about? (It's always set to `0x0`)